# Eclipse: build should stop when one of the builders fails

Tags: eclipse, protocol-buffers

Let's say my project has two builders: The first one is an Ant builder (or possibly just a simple command line builder) that compiles Protocol Buffer files with protoc to generate intermediate java files. The second builder compiles java files including the generated protobuf files.

The problem is that the build process should halt when there is a build error in the first builder phase, but it doesn't. When a builder fails, it just proceeds to the next phase. Is there a way to make it stop when it fails?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I know it's not the subject, but have you considered using http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-dt ?

Comment: Thanks for the info, Everton. I'm not actually using protobuf but it was just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't an easy way to do this. Even though Eclipse builders are ordered they aren't treated as step-by-step instructions for building the project. Each builder is invoked regardless of the output of the previous one. It is up to implementation of each builder to detect problems that are so disruptive that there is no point to running the rest of the builder's logic. For instance, Java Builder aborts if it detects certain types of build path problems.

You can force the behavior that you are after by disabling all of the builders and implementing the entire build as an Ant script, but you'd be giving up a lot to achieve this behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Konstantin. Too bad that there's no such way. :/